# Increase Facebook embed width

Tags: facebook, embed

Short question but so far no solution.
I want a Facebook page embedded om my website.
So I used the Facebook developers page to get it all working but Facebook won't let me use a width over 500px.

Is there any way I can change this? I tried to give the `data-width` attribute a larger number but that won't take. Also CSS isn't an option.

Comment: Nope, not possible. Even if you made the iframe element itself wider, Facebook will limit the width of the content to a maximum of 500px.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks tho'